# How to match anything EXCEPT this string?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I match a string that is NOT `partners`?

Here is what I have that matches partners:

```
/^partners$/i
```

I've tried the following to NOT match partners but doesn't seem to work:

```
/^(?!partners)$/i
```

Comment: I don't know.  But can't you just invert the result returned by whatever regex function you're using?

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex

```
/^(?!partners)$/i
```

only matches empty lines because you didn't include the end-of-line anchor in your lookahead assertion. Lookaheads do just that - they "look ahead" without actually matching any characters, so only lines that match the regex `^$` will succeed.

This would work:

```
/^(?!partners$)/i
```

This reports a match with any string (or, since we're in Ruby here, any line in a multi-line string) that's different from `partners`. Note that it only matches the *empty string* at the start of the line. Which is enough for validation purposes, but the match result will be `""` (instead of `nil` which you'd get if the match failed entirely).

Answer (score 2):

not easily but with the look ahead operator it can.
Here the ruby regex

```
^((?!partners).)*$
```

Cheers

Comment: This matches any string that doesn't *contain* `partners`, which is possibly not what Jacob wanted. At least it's not what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get a true value when string is not `partners` then there is no need to use regex and you can just use a string comparison (which ignores case).

If you for some reason need a positive regex match for any string which does not contain `partners` (if it's a part of a larger regex for example) you could use several different constructs, like:

```
`^(?:(?!partners).)*$`
```

or

```
^(?:[^p]+|p(?!artners))*$
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, in Java:

```
!"partners".equalsIgnoreCase(aString)
```